# How to do a request-promise request from firebase cloud-functions to my app engine django application

Tags: node.js, firebase

I want to do a request-promise post request to a Django application in my google app engine.
The request is from firebase cloud functions.

The problem is, the Django backend requires the request to have csrf token.

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: `https://website.com/account/testfirebase/`,
    body: {},
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': 'token'
    },
    json: true,
  };

  return await requestpromise(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
      console.log(parsedBody);
 
      return parsedBody;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

How can I generate a token from cloud functions that will be accepted by the Django backend in app engine?

```
'X-CSRF-Token': 'token' // I should add the csrf token here.
```

Comment: any news on this ?